# Swift NSAttributedString display blockquotes with indentation

Tags: ios, arrays, nsattributedstring

I get some content with html from the server, and I need to display it in UITextView. The problem is only one - `<blockquote>` tag. iOS displays it as usual text. How can I display `blockquote` tag with left indentations, after convertation from html to nsattributedString this tag is lost from string and I cant find the quotes, or if I try to find range of quotes, after convertation all ranges is invalid. I can't use UIWebView because of pure perfomance. Any help is appreciate.

Comment: You can replace `<blockquote>` and `</blockquote>` with some string, e.g. `|blockquote|` and `|/blockquote|` before conversion, then find it, remove it and apply paragraph style to the given interval.

Comment: @Sulthan this is a really good point, I also tried this option, with the same name for tags `|blockquote|`, but I have to problems - first: if I find content between these tags and remove it, ranges will be affected after removing, also I have problems with finding nested quotes.

Comment: These are not really problems, only difficulties.